# Why does ISBLANK return False not see a blank cell but COUNTBLANK does in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to check if a column is blank. The column is formatted as plain text, so I understand that causes the `ISBLANK` formula to return false, regardless of what is in the cell. But If I use `COUNTBLANKS` on the same range, it counts text cells as blanks. Is there not an easy way to check if no values (numbers or text) appear in a column. Here is an [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A7UJxOK0SCNwwrEPo__XfEO7_LUdCsmfmm9dkzmB0fU/edit#gid=0) here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of `isblank` indicates that this command is meant for one cell only (it's not named `areblank`, after all). Confirmed by trying  the following in a new spreadsheet: `=isblank(A1)` is True, `=isblank(A2)` is True, but `isblank(A1:A2)` is False, simply because A1:A2 is not a *single blank cell*.

If you want to check whether a given column (like C2:C10) is empty, `countblanks` is one option, and another is comparing `=sum(len(C2:C10))` to 0. The latter method treats empty string "" same as blank cells.